# What accent is it?

Tags: pronunciation, accent

Came across a video from someone on youtube. It's a cover of a song. I like his pronunciation. I'm not a native English speaker, so I wonder if anyone could place his accent. Where is it from? He doesn't sound native at some words.

[the video](https://youtu.be/WEyt7eSP02s)

Comment: Hard to say just by listening to him sing. Most people pronounce things differently when they sing compared to how they speak. His feed doesn't have any videos of him speaking plainly, though. My guess is Russian. The accent at least sounds Eastern European.

Answer (score 3):

He sounds English to me (I'm English and listen to a lot of people who perform this way) but he doesn't have a strong regional  accent. I thought he was a Received Pronunciation speaker at first but then realised that some of his vowel sounds (particularly the 'a'  in the word 'last') were similar to my own so I would place him in the Lancashire, Yorkshire, Derbyshire,  Cheshire sort of area.

Having said that there are some Welsh people who have a somewhat similar accent, particularly when singing. People's accents are often distorted a lot when they are singing, though. It's much more difficult to place a singing voice than a speaking one. If someone told me that he came from Lincolnshire, Devon, Cornwall or even the West Midlands it wouldn't surprise me.

His guitar playing is superb, though.

Comment: That singer is not a native English speaker. His accent sounds Eastern European, maybe Russian or Ukrainian.

Comment: @RMac as native BrE speaker, I placed the singer as UK or possibly Eire. There is a slight 'oi' sound to the 'i' vowel, but I can't place its region. The  youtube domain though, is Belgium which I understand is used by many other nationalities.

Answer (score 0):

Probably Russian, as his YouTube page seems to show :
https://www.youtube.com/user/LexRomah/featured

Comment: Well spotted. However I suspect that he's British educated. The 'northern English' vowel sounds I heard could easily be Russian, I suppose, but British educated foreigners often have accents which are indistinguishable from native speakers. Sandi Toksvig is famously Danish, for instance, but sounds quintessentially English to me.